# error: cannot access Task class file for bolts

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, sinch

Im working through the tutorial given [here](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/) and im stuck at the section of code posted below:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);
  }

  //display clickable a list of all users
  private void setConversationsList() {
      currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
      names = new ArrayList<String>();

      ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
      query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
      query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
          public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
```

it is failing on `ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();`

with

> Error:(53, 14) error: cannot access Task
>   class file for bolts.Task not found

I'm having difficulty following this (knowing what files these code chunks go in) as im totally green at android dev.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Hey if you ended up using the answer below, could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Parse library depends on a library called Bolt which is in the same folder with the Parse library downloaded from the Parse.com website.

This is for Android Studio, but it should be similar for Eclipse.

Copy and past the Bolt library from the unzipped folder into the 'libs' folder of your project. You can also just copy and paste the entire unzipped library folder into the 'libs' folder. Right click on the 'Parse-.jar' file and select 'Add as library' or similar if it isn't already added. Do the same for the 'bolts-android-.jar' file. Try to run the project again and everything should work.