# Adding bolts to an android studio project

Tags: gradle

I'm currently running into this error:

> [error: cannot access Task class file for bolts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601421/error-cannot-access-task-class-file-for-bolts)

the problem is, once I follow the suggestion for solution (Adding the bolts jar from the Parse library), I'm getting *this* error:

> [:app:dexDebug ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001051/appdexdebug-execexception-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2)

Looking at the solution here, it seems seems that the problem is with one of my jars (the one which i just added, apparently), and the solution would be *removing* it...

Any idea how to get out of this deadlock?

Comment: i think you have reached the 65535 method limit....use [this tool](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts) to check .... or you need to enable multidex support